# How to check if one array contains value that is the same?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm learning about Java array and got stuck on this problem.
I want to add the value of num and delete duplicate name if the name if equals.
Thank you in advanced.
Here's a little bit of my code:

```
public static void main(String[]Args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    System.out.println("Input n= ");
    n=input.nextInt();
    String name[] = new String[n];
    int num[] = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        System.out.println("Input name= ");
        name[i]= input.next();
        System.out.println("Input num= ");
        num[i]=input.nextInt();
    }

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){       
System.out.println(name[i] + " " + num[i]);

    }
```

### I'm expecting the result to be:

Example1 5

Example2 6

### IF I input n=3

name[1]="Example1"

name[2] = "Example2"

name[3] = "Example1"

num[1] = 2

num[2] = 6

num[3] = 3

### The actual result is:

Example1 2

Example2 6

Example1 3

Comment: Where does `5` come from in `Example1 5`?

Comment: I want to add the value of num and delete duplicate name, if the name if equals. So 2+3

Comment: Please add `;` to the end of each line to your code. Without `;`, the code doesn't look like java.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that arrays starts at 0. This solution won't clear array so you will need to modify some of that to shift both arrays to left.

```
int n = 3;
    String[] name = new String[n];
    int[] num= new int[n];
    
    name[0] = "Example1";
    name[1] = "Example2";
    name[2] = "Example1";
    num[0] = 2;
    num[1] = 6;
    num[2] = 3;
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < name.length; j++) {
            if (name[i].equals(name[j])) {
                num[i] += num[j];
                num[j] = 0;
                name[j] = null;
            }
        }
    }


    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if (name[i] != null) {
            System.out.println(name[i] + " " + num[i]);
        }
    }
```

Output:

> Example1 5
>
> Example2 6

Comment: I've tried your code, it worked.
However, when i replace the arrays(name[0,1,2] , num[0,1,2]) with scanner input, the code "if (name[i] == name[j])" doesn't triggered despite being equals value, am i missing something?

Comment: @Ro Try using if (name[i].equals(name[j])) instead of if (name[i] == name[j])

Answer (score 0):

The following program accomplishes what you are after:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 2;
    String[] name = {"Example1", "Example2"};
    int[] num = {5, 6};

    //this is a comment

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      System.out.println(name[i] + "  " + num[i]);
    }

  }
}
```

You need to declare an array for `num`, `name`, and you also need to change your `n` value to 2 if you want to keep your loop format and only print out two elements.

Comment: In java, you denote comments with a `//` symbol. I'll edit to show

Comment: No, i mean can i paste code in this comment section?

Comment: Try not to paste code in the comments. Instead, you can edit your question to explain what you need, and post it there.